# How to translate NavigationView menu button?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, language-translation

I develop a UWP app and it supports two languages: en-US and DE.

The translations work flawless so far but during testing I noticed that the menu button (well, the tooltip) of the navigation view is not yet translated. The rest shows up in German, so the system clearly detects that I'm using this language for the other controls/texts:
[image]

I searched for "Close Navigation" and "Open Navigation" but it's nowhere in my source. I  then search the documentation but there seems to be no property to get the menu button.

Does anybody know how to translate this control?

Comment: What language is the operating system set to? If English then I'd assume it's being provided by the framework. Change it to German and check again.

Comment: I use english as windows display language and de_CH as region and keyboard layout. As other translations work, I guess this control is not translated because it's translations would be included in a Window language as it is a control originating from the framework. Don't want to download a language (pack) to translate this, so I hope there is a way to translate it manually.

Comment: Region & keyboard settings won't do anything for you here. Show how you're switching the language in your app

Comment: I don't switch anything. I have a resource file for language A and one for B. The rest is done by UWP. I use x:Uid="xy" for the controls and use this UID in the resource files to translate them. For texts that are not directly related to a control I translate them with: ResourceRetriever.GetString("strXy")

Comment: Oh I see, you're getting the German locale through the Region & Language settings. You could try setting `ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride` on application launched